# Unconventional Crop In Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, artboard, crop, images

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mEWzQ16.jpg]

I need to crop this image in such a way that the space below "submit your picture here!" is taken out, because I'm going to use that space for a "choose file" form on my website. I tried creating a custom artboard, but illustrator only lets you use a traditional rectangle or square as an artboard. Basically, I need a vector image, but I'm not sure how to do this since there are three separate images. Any suggestions for how to go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**All digital images are rectangular**. All images. There's no such thing as a non-rectangular digital image.

What you *can* do is create a transparent area within that rectangle. The transparency will make it *seems* as though there's an empty space when there actually isn't.

Illustrator, by default has a transparent background (even though it looks white in the application). If you save and artboard as a PNG24 file, then artboard background will *not* be there. You may need to rethink the format you are saving the image to.

For your particular usage, you probably don't even need transparency. You could use CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) to place the rectangular image *behind* your form and allow the form to sit on top of the image rather than trying to cut the image area.

<kbd>[**Here is a very quick and dirty sample of this method.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/jzyp9wwr/4/)</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using pseudo elements to place them around the form. This will allow them to be more responsive and give more control in general

Comment: I agree @ZachSaucier . Using 2 image elements on the left and right would be better, and set the headline as live HTML.

Comment: The problem is if I place the form on top of the image, the whole thing will be a white rectangle, and I have a background that I would like to show behind the form. I actually tried to fix this problem by breaking the text and two arrows up into separate components, but I am not advanced enough in html to know how to get rid of the space between the images and text http://i.imgur.com/jLUYyxa.jpg ,so I just tried to make the whole thing one image instead. This is why knowing how to create a transparent area would help.

Comment: Assuming the Illustrator files does **not** have a white box in it, just save the artboard as a PNG24 file. It'll be transparent where there is nothing. You may need to fill the arrows with white if they aren't already.